# Integral inequation

Tags: calculus, statistics, integration, inequality

In my statistics book Chebyshev's inequality is proven. In several steps this inequality is used:

$$ \int_a^{+\infty} \phi(x) f_X(x)dx \quad \geq \quad \phi(a) \int_a^{+\infty} f_X(x)dx $$

and also:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{-a} \phi(x) f_X(x)dx \quad \geq \quad \phi(-a) \int_{-\infty}^{-a} f_X(x)dx $$

Here is $a \geq 0$, $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ a positive function, and $f_X$ a pdf.

Why this is valid?

Comment: Is there any other conditions on $\phi$?

Comment: Of what step do you not understand its validity?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal read the first to last line ;)

Comment: Is $\phi$ an increasing function?

Comment: Yes, $\phi$ is increasing. But in one part of the theorem only for $x \geq 0$ and the other $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so I figured it was not relevant for this step.

Comment: Check [Markov's Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MarkovsInequality.html).

Comment: As @MhenniBenghorbal also just pointed out, the proof of Chebyshev's inequality is the easiest through Markov's inequality. So I would advise you to first go through the proof of Markov's inequality and then read this http://planetmath.org/proofofchebyshevsinequality

Comment: Maybe the simplest explanation is that simply $\phi(x) f_X(x) \geq \phi(a) f_X(x)$, since $\phi$ is increasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is increasing (this is important here) and $f_X$ is positive, we have for $a>0$ and $x\ge a$, $\phi(x)\ge\phi(a)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^\infty\phi(x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\int_a^\infty\phi(a)f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\phi(a)\int_a^\infty f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
$$
The other inequality is simply a change of variables.

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive reason why $$ \int_{a}^{+\infty} \phi(x) f_X(x)dx \quad \geq \quad \phi(a) \int_{a}^{+\infty} f_X(x)dx $$ is that we are integrating $\phi(x)$ from $a$ to $+\infty$, hence if we evaluate $\phi(x)$ at the lower limit of that integral ($\phi(a)$ is $\phi(x)$ evaluated at the lower limit of the integral), this result will always be smaller than the integral itself. You can see this best by making a picture of a positive valued function and see in the picture what the integral represents and what the value of the function evaluated at the lower limit of the integral represents. Though this is not a formal proof, it might help your understanding.