# A bound for error function

Tags: probability, functions

I am looking for a bound (or dominated function) of $\text{erf}(x)$ where $\text{erf}$ is defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Thank you very much.

Comment: Here are inequalities for a related function: http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.8

Comment: [Another reference](https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/frank/notes/erfc.pdf) for bounds on the $\mathrm{erfc}$. A more citeable reference in this regard might be the [Handbook of Mathematical Functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/) by Abramowitz and Stegun

Answer (score 3):

Well, $erf(x)\le1$; that's probably not the bound you want. But if you're talking about large $x$ that's the best bound on $erf(x)$ that you're going to get.

Seems to me what matters is how small $1-erf(x)$ is for large $x$. For that you want to bound the "complementary error function": If $x>0$ then

$$\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt\le\frac1{2x}\int_x^\infty 2te^{-t^2}\,dt
=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}\quad(x>0).$$

At first blush that looks like a pretty bad estimate, since $t$ is much larger than $x$ on most of the interval $(x,\infty)$. But it's actually fairly sharp,  because the exponential dies so fast.

Of course there's a similar bound on $erf(x)$ for large negative values of $x$: $$\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-t^2}\,dt\le\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2|x|}\quad(x<0).$$

Comment: I had to see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414203/integral-inequation to understand this inequality