# Expected value exponential inequality non-negative random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable and $p \geq e$, $q > 0$ be two constant values such that
$$
P [X \geq x] \leq p e^{-x^2/q^2} \quad \forall x \geq 0.
$$
Prove that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] \leq q(1+\sqrt{\log p}).
$$

There's my first attempt. Using the identity
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) d x - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x) d x
$$
and the fact that $X \geq 0$ I obtain:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) d x
$$
and using the hypothesis I get
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \int_0^{+\infty} p e^{-x^2/q^2} d x = pq \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-z^2} dz = \frac{pq \sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$
where the last equality is given by the [gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

But then I'm stuck.

The second attempt I tried was to partition the events set in some smart way, that is using $( X \geq q )$ or $(X \geq \sqrt{\log p} )$ but I couldn't go anywhere.

Comment: The inequality for the expected value of $X$ should not have an $x$ in it, since you should have integrated $x$ away.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to derive an inequality for $E[X]$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the inequality I had to prove. Now I edited.

Comment: As John Barber said, you didn't apply the hypothesis properly : you have 
$$\mathbb P(X\ge x) \le  p e^{-x^2/q^2}\ \ \forall x\ge 0 $$
Which implies by integrating that
$$\mathbb{E}[X] \le \int_0^\infty p e^{-x^2/q^2}\ d x $$

Comment: @StratosFair you're right! I did it right on the paper but then I wrongly typed the question here. Now I've edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By replacing $X$ with $X/q$, we can w.l.o.g. assume $q = 1$.

Note that the inequality $\mathbb{P}(X \ge x) \le p e^{-x^2}$ is a strong inequality for large $x$, but rather poor for small $x$. Indeed, for $x = 0$ this only yields $\mathbb{P}(X \ge x) \le p$, which by assumption is greater than $e$. Since Probabilities are bounded by $1$, this inequality is poor when $pe^{-x^2} > 1$, or equivalently $x < \sqrt{\log(p)}$. We should therefore split up the integral:

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \ge x) \,dx = \int_0^\sqrt{\log(p)} \mathbb{P}(X \ge x) \, dx + \int_{\sqrt{\log(p)}}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \ge x) \, dx.$$

Now the first term is bounded by $\sqrt{\log(p)}$. For the second term, use the inequality in the assumption, as well as $e^{-x^2} \le x e^{-x^2}$ for $x \ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For $z\geq 0$

$$\Bbb E [X]  =  \Bbb E [X 1_{\{X< z\}}] + \Bbb E [X1_{\{X\ge z\}}] \leq z \Bbb P (X< z) + \int_0^\infty \Bbb P(X1_{\{X \ge z\}} \geq x) dx\\
=z \Bbb P (X< z) + \int_0^z \Bbb P(X \ge z) dx  +\int_z^\infty \Bbb P(X \geq x) dx \\
= z + \int_z^\infty \Bbb P (X\geq x) dx  = z + \int_0^\infty \Bbb P (X\geq x+z)dx\\ \leq z+\int_0^\infty e^{- \left( \frac{x^2}{q^2} + \frac{z^2}{q^2} - \log (p) \right)} e^{-\frac{2xz}{q^2}}dx\\
= z+ q \int_0^\infty e^{- \left( x^2 + \frac{z^2}{q^2} - \log (p) \right)} e^{-\frac{2xz}{q}} dx  
$$

Thus for $z= q \sqrt{\log (p)}$ we have

$$\Bbb E [X]  \leq q \sqrt{\log (p)} + q \int_0^\infty e^{-  x^2} e^{-2x \sqrt{\log (p)}} dx \leq q \sqrt{\log (p)} + q \int_0^\infty e^{-  x^2} e^{-2x } dx\\
=q \sqrt{\log (p)} + q \int_0^\infty e^{- (x^2 +2x +1) +1}  dx = q \sqrt{\log (p)} + q \int_0^\infty e^{- (x+1)^2 +1}  dx\\
= q \sqrt{\log (p)} + q e^1 \int_1^\infty e^{- x^2}  dx$$
Using this bound [A bound for error function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761036/a-bound-for-error-function)
$$\int_1^\infty e^{- x^2}  dx \leq \frac{e^{-1}}2$$
we get
$$\Bbb E [X] \leq q \sqrt{\log (p)} + \frac q 2$$

Comment: thank you for your reply! Anyway I can't get the intuition behind the first split: it's a general way to prove this kind of inequalities? Can you give me more insights?

Comment: Actually, the former first equality (which is now the first inequality) should have been an inequality. I corrected it and filled in some details. Dominik's answer is far better and more elegant, though, even if the same way of solving this is behind it.